# Reading strings of data with delimiter and storing into struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, delimiter

i need some help with some problems I've encountered. I'm new to C language and i need help trying to read a strings of data with delimiters inbetween and saving them into a struc. how can i go about doing this?

The string's format goes like, format is A:B:C:D:E
examples
0002:0001:0001:0042:ASD
0001:0011:0010:0023:DDD

When the string is being read, it is being validated and stored into the struct at the same time.

A's value should be within 1-100
B's value should be within 1-100
C's value should be within 1-10
D's value should be within 1-50
E's value should be within 25 characters.

Can anyone guide me on how can i be able to write the code? I am sorry if this sounds easy but im really new to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;
   char * aline;
   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      } 

       printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

       while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){




   aline=(strtok,":");
   while (aline != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",aline);
    aline = strtok (NULL, " :");
  }}
     fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `strtok()`. You should post your code, show us what you have tried. Where you are facing problems.

Comment: i don't even know how to start about. ): @1336087

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line, `strtok` to tokenize your string, `strtol` to convert each token. BTW is this your homework?

Comment: @1336087 am i not supposed/allowed to ask homework. im sorry i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the structure with `sscanf` or `fscanf`

```
sscanf(string, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%26s", &struc->A, &struc->B, &struc->C,
                                   &struc->D,  sturc->E);

fscanf(file, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%26s", &struc->A, &struc->B, &struc->C,
                                 &struc->D,  sturc->E);
```

to validate the string you can check to see if the null character was overwritten, just make sure that you declare the string with an extra character.

```
if (struc->E[26] != '\0') {
    struc->E[26] = '\0';
    goto invalid;
}
```

validating the other fields would be simple bounds checking

```
if (struc->A < 1 || struc->A > 100) goto invalid;
```

You should also take note that the `scanf` functions do not always fill every field , and will return the number of fields that they fill. So you should check the number returned by that if you are expecting irregular input.

```
if (scanf(...) != 5) {
    // either populate with default values or invalidate
}
```

Comment: my data string is from a text file. how do i modify sscanf to make it work? @kdhp

Comment: I added an example with `fscanf`.

Comment: thank you. how do i print out the data stored in the struct? i tried `printf("%c",&st.E[1]);` but it doesnt work.

Comment: @JamesBond007 In `printf` statements `%c` expects a character and you are passing it a pointer. `&st.E[1] == &(*(st.E + 1)) == st.E + 1` If you keep an extra character at the end of the string, and keep it equivalent to `'\0'` then `st.E` is null terminated and can be treated like any other C string. `printf("%s", st.E)`

Comment: i'm a little confused. so u mean i should change my statement to `printf("%s", st.E)` ?

Comment: @JamesBond007 If you maintain the `\0` terminator, yes. `scanf` functions will write a null terminated string unless it reads too many characters. If you want to print character by character (`%c`) you have to pass `printf` a `char`. `&st.E[1]` is not a `char`, it is a `char *`, a pointer to a character, or an address. `%s` however, expects a C string, or a null terminated string, and prints the string up to the null terminator. And unless the string was invalid `st.E` will be a valid C string.

Comment: @JamesBond007 An even easier way to print your string would be `printf("%.25s", st.E)`, if you got the string from a `scanf` function, or any other C string source, then that will always work.

Comment: @JamesBond007 By "a `scanf` function" I mean `scanf`, `sscanf`, or `fscanf`. If you did not use one of those functions, then which one did you use?

Comment: this is my code brother,`struct Foo
{
    char E[51];
    int A,B,C,D;
}st;

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;
   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   fscanf(fp, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%51s", &st.A, &st.B, &st.C,
                                 &st.D,  &st.E);


    printf("%c",&st.E[1]);
     fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}`

Comment: @JamesBond007 First, `st.E` is already an address so you do not need the `&`. `scanf(fp, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%51s", &st.A, &st.B, &st.C, &st.D, st.E)` Second, if you want to print all 51 characters use `printf("%.51s", st.E)`, and if you want to print 1 character use `printf("%c", st.E[1])`. For a full explanation of format specifiers look at [`man printf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=3) and [`man scanf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fscanf&sektion=3)